# How to run the Kotlin/Native win32 sample

Tags: windows, winapi, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to run Kotlin/Native v0.3 win32 sample by following the blog at https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/06/kotlinnative-v0-3-is-out/

1. I downloaded the x86-64 Windows zip file as instructed at the end of the blog.
2. I run `kotlin-native-windows-0.3\samples>gradlew.bat` and it
   downloaded something and said 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL'. (I'm not sure if
   this step is necessary)

   2.1 But If I run `kotlin-native-windows-0.3\samples>gradlew build` 
   in this folder, I got some failures:

   C:\Users\OO\Documents\kotlin-native-windows-0.3\samples>gradlew build
   :concurrent:assemble UP-TO-DATE
   :concurrent:check UP-TO-DATE
   :concurrent:downloadKonanCompiler
   :concurrent:genMessageChannelInteropStubs UP-TO-DATE
   :concurrent:compileCpp FAILED

   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   - What went wrong:
     Execution failed for task ':concurrent:compileCpp'.

     > A problem occurred starting process 'command './buildCpp.sh''
   - Try:
     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

   BUILD FAILED
3. Then I run `kotlin-native-windows-0.3\samples\win32>build.bat` and I
   got another error.

`C:\Users\OO\Documents\kotlin-native-windows-0.3\samples\win32>build.bat
exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find "win32" in [C:\Users\OO\Documents\kotlin-native-windows-0.3\samples\win32, C:\Users\OO\.konan\klib, C:\Users\OO\DOCUME~1\KOTLIN~1.3\bin\..\klib].
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.library.KonanLibrarySearchPathResolver.resolve(SearchPathResolver.kt:71)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanConfig$librariesFound$2.invoke(KonanConfig.kt:70)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanConfig$librariesFound$2.invoke(KonanConfig.kt:34)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:130)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanConfig.getLibrariesFound(KonanConfig.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanConfig.access$getLibrariesFound$p(KonanConfig.kt:34)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanConfig$libraries$2.invoke(KonanConfig.kt:77)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanConfig$libraries$2.invoke(KonanConfig.kt:34)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:130)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanConfig.getLibraries$backend_native_compiler(KonanConfig.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanConfig.loadLibMetadata(KonanConfig.kt:90)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanConfig.<init>(KonanConfig.kt:80)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:66)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:56)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:93)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:46)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:90)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:68)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:34)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:160)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:151)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$main$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:169)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$main$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:166)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.util.UtilKt.profileIf(util.kt:33)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.util.UtilKt.profile(util.kt:28)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion.main(K2Native.kt:168)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2NativeKt.main(K2Native.kt:174)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.main(main.kt:46)`

I'm very new to Kotlin or Gradle world, I don't know if this is the way to compile the samples.

What additional packages should I install?

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily solved by canceled the comments "rem call ..." in "build.bat"